# Vue child component property does not work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, quasar-framework

I am trying to break this code [A] (see fiddle at bottom):

```
  <div class="q-uploader-files scroll">
      <q-item
        v-for="file in files"
        :key="file.name"
      >
        <q-progress :percentage="file.__progress"/>
        <div>
          {{ file.__progress }}%
        </div>

        <q-item-side v-if="file.__img" :image="file.__img.src">
        </q-item-side>
        <q-item-side right>
          <q-item-tile
            :icon="file.__doneUploading ? 'mdi-done' : 'mdi-clear'"
            :color="file.__doneUploading ? 'primary' : 'color'"
            @click.native="__remove(file)"></q-item-tile>
        </q-item-side>
      </q-item>
    </div>
```

into [B] the basically the same code but then with a child component. 
Here the parent:

```
<div class="q-uploader-files scroll">
  <my-uploader-progress
    v-for="file in files"
    :file="file"
    :key="file.name"
    :color='color'
  >
  </my-uploader-progress>
</div>
```

And here the child:

```
<template>
  <q-item>
    <q-progress
      :color="file.__failed ? 'negative' : 'grey'"
      :percentage="file.__progress"
    />
    <div>
      {{ file.__progress }}%
    </div>

    <q-item-side v-if="file.__img" :image="file.__img.src"/>
    <q-item-side v-else icon="mdi-file" :color="color"/>
    <q-item-main :label="file.name" :sublabel="file.__size"/>

    <q-item-side right>
      <q-item-tile
        :icon="file.__doneUploading ? 'mdi-done' : 'mdi-clear'"
        :color="file.__doneUploading ? 'primary' : 'color'"
        @click.native="__remove(file)"
      />
    </q-item-side>
  </q-item>
</template>
```

On the child I have set the `file` property:

```
  props: {
    file: {
      type: File,
      required: true
    }
  },
```

Somehow in the parent-child code there must be a problem as the `file` __img property does not exist in the child (at render) in [B] see:

[image]

, whereas it does exist in [A]:

[image]

What's wrong? There are no errors in the console.

The original ([A]) code is from [here](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/blob/v0.17.16/src/components/uploader/QUploader.js). The [File Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) consists of a xhr instance (I suppose?!).

Here fiddles/ sandboxes for [[A]](https://codesandbox.io/s/onlv1o1p6) and for [[B]](https://codesandbox.io/s/710yom0p9j). Press ADD and select an image to upload, it will not upload but [A] will show its thumbnail img etc; do the same for [B] and these will not show.

NOTA BENE: I noticed that the `file.__img` does not show first in [B], but when I start editing code in the child component..., it suddenly SHOWS. So apparently/ maybe it is something asynchronous and after a render-refresh it is there...?!

Comment: Can you try changing the props to something like below?

```  props: {
    file: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },```

Comment: It gives a Vue error saying wrong type and should be File type. Apparently File is a custom type https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Type-Checks

Comment: Exact error when making Array: `vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:587 [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "file". Expected Array, got File.`

Comment: Can you share a jsfiddle link?

Comment: @ShubhamPatel I added fiddles!

Comment: Have you tried it somewhere else? other than sandbox editor?

Comment: @waleedali Yes. In my own code. I only made the sandboxes to show similar behavior (as requested by Shubham Patel).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make the property value reactive by returning a factory function.

```
props: {
  file: {
    type: File,
    required: true,
    default: function () {
        return {
          name: '',
          _progress: 0
        }
      }
  }
},
```

Comment: How would that work exactly for the codesandbox example? The props default will be 'overwritten' right!?

Comment: The object you return for the default should contain any missing object keys your app may by complaining about being missing so they have an empty value at the very least for the component to use during an idle state until some valid input becomes available, as soon as input occurs the default will be overwritten and the new value will be considered reactive because you returned an object beforehand and that will allow inheritance to function as expected.

Comment: Cool. Sounds swell.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a working solution you can simply assign a key to the `my-uploader-progress` component based on the presence of an `__img` property, which will force it to re-render when the property becomes available ..

```
<my-uploader-progress
        v-for="file in files"
        :file="file"
        :key="file.__img ? '1-' + file.name : '0-' + file.name"
        :hide-upload-progress="hideUploadProgress"
        :color='color'
>
</my-uploader-progress>
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/moqz23858y)

Comment: Yeah, that is what I use now.

Answer (score 4):

Sort of an ugly hack, but I hope this will fix the issue. Try setting a timeout in the mounted function to buy some time before the file gets loaded and then true the `v-if` condition to load image element in the DOM.

```
<template>
  <q-item-side v-if="file_loaded" :image="file.__img.src"/>
</template>

<script>
data () {
  file_loaded: false
},
mounted() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.file_loaded = true
  }, 1000)
}
</script>
```

I have tried this in your sandbox [[B]](https://codesandbox.io/s/4jm157rz77) and it's working fine.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that works as the __img property comes from a Promise in the parent (whereas e.g. the name property is synchronous). Besides workarounds, I am also interested why it does not show? I mean even when it is not there at mount, it should update from the property as the property is reactive, right?

Comment: Well, that's because deeply nested objects are not much reactive, I guess. Therefore, it would be great if you use a Boolean for this purpose.

Comment: Well, if the __img property of file is not reactive, it should not show in the 'one component' solution as well, but it does? I can not see why they differ in behavior.

Comment: They are different, at least, in a way. in 'one component' the property `file` is initialized as empty and then you watch for changes in it's property `__img` whereas in the 'child component' the property `file` is not present at the time of component initialization and therefor Vue is not able to detect changes in it's nested property `__img`  

see `Change Detection Caveats` here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html for more detailed explanation

Comment: I think `file` is present in the child at initialization, just not its property __img. I knew/ know about the caveat, however when that is causing the issue, why does it work in the 'one component' solution? I don't see something equivalent to $set being used on __img in the 'one component' solution?!

Comment: BTW If the added property caveat is causing this, can it be solved in the child with $set ? How?

Comment: I am not sure (or at least I am not aware) you can do it that way. Another thing you can do is, use `v-if="file.__img"` in the parent component (while looping for rendering child components). That would then only render the child component once the file is properly loaded and `__img` property is present in the `file` object

Comment: I like your last suggestion! It does mess up the logic on files that do not have thumbnail though. It also does not answer the theoretical part of this question. You definitely gave the best answer so far!

Answer (score 4):

If you are updating the property value of an object in props after the child has been mounted it wont work, you would have to replace the complete object to make it work,